# ENOENT: no such file or directory while exporting csv files in electron app

Tags: node.js, electron

I am facing some errors while I try to save the csv files in another folder under the documents directory in the electron app. It only happens when i try to use relative paths but does not occur if i try to save in the same documents directory.  so i have read a number of error no such file directory in nodejs applications and tried them but I am not having any success.   i am interested in electron app on window machine.

```
 Failed to export the csv file [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\hellomachine\Documents\invoicer\Expenses.csv'] {
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: 'C:\\Users\\hellomachine\\Documents\\invoicer\\Expenses.csv'
}
```

This is the code that I have tried utilising but no success.

```
//const exportFolder = app.getPath('documents') //this works well since they are in same directory
const exportFolder = `${app.getPath('documents')}/invoicer`;//this fails as there is relative paths or directory
//let csvFilePath = __dirname(`${exportFolder}/${fileName}.csv`) //this failed to write the file
    //let csvFilePath = exportFolder + `/invoicer/${fileName}.csv`
    let csvFilePath = exportFolder + `/${fileName}.csv`
    //fs.writeFile(csvFilePath, csvData, (err)=>{
    fs.writeFile(path.join(__dirname, csvFilePath), csvData, (err)=>{
        if (err) {
            console.log('Failed to export the csv file', err) 
        }
        console.log('successful exported the csv file')
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

After alot of debugging on windows, it is better to first create the sub directory in the documents folder and then you can write the csv file there.

```
const exportFolder = path.join(app.getPath('documents'), './invoicer/');
//solution is to first create the above sub directory if it does not exist.
const timeSubDirectory = `${exportFolder}/${generateTimeBasedSubDirectory()}`
fs.mkdir( timeSubDirectory, {recursive:true}, function(err){
    if (err) {
        reject('Failed to create the export sub directory' + err)
   }
    exportArray.forEach((item,i)=>{
        let fileName = timeSubDirectory + `/${item.group}.csv` //csv file
         createCSVFile(fileName, item.groupItems)
         if (i === lastItem) {
             resolve('Completed exporting all files') 
         }
   })

       })
    
  function createCSVFile(fileName, csvData){
        fs.writeFile(fileName, csvData, (err)=>{
        if (err) {
            console.log('Failed to export the csv file', err) 
        }
        console.log('successful exported the csv file')
       }) 
    }
```